# selecting a specific date from the data based on a comparison to a different row

Tags: sql, date, window-functions

I have the below rows of data for one PO. In this situation I need to select the date when the items move into inspection and compare it to today.  The emphasized date from the image.  I know this is the date I need because the previous row shows zero in inspection 'Insp' when sorted by date.  That is the most recent date that parts moved to inspection.  Can anyone write a sql that will select the most recent date into inspection and compare it to today to show how many days the parts have been in inspection?

```
ID  PO  Line    Rec Insp    Rej Transaction_Date
7616    263309  1   0   48  0   9/23/21 7:47 AM
7931    263309  1   0   0   48  10/12/21 7:36 AM
**13643 263309  1   0   42  48  9/21/22 9:39 AM**
13818   263309  1   0   42  0   9/28/22 4:27 PM
13819   263309  1   0   42  48  9/28/22 4:27 PM
13953   263309  1   0   42  0   10/4/22 7:55 AM
13955   263309  1   0   42  42  10/4/22 8:03 AM
13956   263309  1   0   42  0   10/4/22 8:04 AM
14011   263309  1   0   42  0   10/4/22 12:31 PM
14012   263309  1   0   42  0   10/4/22 12:31 PM
```

I have pulled the minimum date which in most cases is the date I need, but doesn't work if the parts have moved out and back into inspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are looking for the latest inspection entry for each PO, where an inspection entry is the row that immediately follows a row with `0` in `Insp`.

We can use `lag` to retrieve the "last" value of `Insp` and use that to filter on the inspection entries ; then, `row_number()` can be used to filter on the latest row per `po`.

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by po order by transaction_date desc) rn
    from (
        select t.*,
            lag(insp) over(partition by po order by transaction_date desc) lag_insp
        from mytable t
    ) t
    where lag_insp = 0
) t
where rn = 1
```